# How to merge two database with same field but data should not be duplicate?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two .sql database and I want to merge data of these two databse but the data should not be duplicate. Both database contain same data also I want to ignore same data and the data which is not present in main database should be inserted in it from another database .
database one and two both have NAME field in them so the name which are identical should drop and other should be inserted.

```
for example
db1 have author_name         db2 have author_name
         KARAN                      RAM  
         KISAN                      LAXMAN 
         MAYUR                      MAYUR
         RAM                        RAHIM

After Merging the result should be
DB1 author_name
     KARAN 
     KISAN 
     MAYUR 
     RAM 
     LAXMAN 
     RAHIM
```

Comment: I don't get it. The new database has more columns? Could you please give an example with sample_data which we can understand?

Comment: Are you sure you meant database and not tables?

Comment: ya i m sure i want to merge two databse....name is the table in both with coloumn name author_name

Answer (score 1):

This question is a little ambiguous but I believe I understand the question - you simply want to merge two database dumps into a single table.

Let's assume your table is called `authors` and you have 2 databases (as you describe `db1` and `db2`.  Your schema is simply:

```
+-------------+
| column      |
+-------------+
| id          |
| author_name |
+-------------+
```

First of all you mention you have 2 .sql files I assume have been generated with `mysqldump` - Make sure your `author_name` column has a unique index set.

```
ALTER TABLE db1.authors ADD UNIQUE INDEX `UNI_authors_author_name` (`author_name`)
```

Then modify both of the SQL files and change the INSERt queries from:

```
INSERT INTO db1.authors
```

to

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO db1.authors
```

This simply ignores the errors mysql would throw when you attempt to insert duplicate content.  The Unique index forces unique records and this case you do not need to edit the record so `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will not help you.

Comment: i am not able to understand what you mean to say...Yes I have 2 .sql files one is db1.sql and othther is db2.sql and both have table authors in it how to merge these database without dupliate value..please tell me step by step